# I'm stuck trying to fill page width with SVG

Tags: html, css, image, svg

Admittedly, I'm new to SVG, but I've tried several different variations of the code below with no luck.  I simply want to expand the SVG shape and image to fill the page width.  I also want to shorten the height.  My goal is to make this a site header/banner (with blur with text/logo over it).

Any help would be very appreciated.  TIA!

```
<html>

<style>

body{background-color: black;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<svg width="100%" height="370px" viewBox="0 0 1148.942 598.47" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
        <!--<image xlink:href="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/RnUAAOSwG1JakMvr/s-l1600.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="680" />-->
        <image  xlink:href="https://images.furnituredealer.net/img/collections%2Fsignature_design_by_ashley%2Fdarcy%207500_75000-lsg-b5.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="680" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#img1)" d="M1145.237,3.395H3.379v592c0,0,247.108-160.416,1141-99L1145.237,3.395z"/>

</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris is right, you need to set aspect ratio preservation to xMidYMax slice.

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice"
```

But he missed the part with the fixed height of 370px.
For this use case it is good to set a wrapper with `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden`

Here it is:

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 1148.942 598.47" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="101%" height="101%">
              <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"  xlink:href="https://images.furnituredealer.net/img/collections%2Fsignature_design_by_ashley%2Fdarcy%207500_75000-lsg-b5.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <path fill="url(#img1)" d="M1145.237,3.395H3.379v592c0,0,247.108-160.416,1141-99L1145.237,3.395z"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <h1> Hello World! </h1>
</body>
```

I added some colors and text, to make it vivid.

Comment: I like what you did here.  Working in ie, but Chrome isn't showing rounded bottom

Comment: ^^^^ Other than this, it's working beautifully for what I need.

Comment: Any thoughts on why Chrome might not be drawing the rounded bottom?

Comment: Ok, removed overflow: hidden, and now working.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Primarily just need to tweak your aspect ratio preservation to `xMidYMax slice`, see example and hope it helps. Cheers!

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1148.942 598.47" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
        <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"  xlink:href="https://images.furnituredealer.net/img/collections%2Fsignature_design_by_ashley%2Fdarcy%207500_75000-lsg-b5.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#img1)" d="M1145.237,3.395H3.379v592c0,0,247.108-160.416,1141-99L1145.237,3.395z"/>
</svg>
```